# Tutorial about XMLObject

Tags: java, xml, apache-axis, xmlbeans

Appreciate anyone could point me to a nice tutorial of using XMLObject from org.apache.xmlbeans. I have been doing axis2 which gives me a response of XMLObject. However, I can't get to the getTextContent().

After googling for hours, I realise I maybe need to convert the XMLObject back to ArrayList or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `toString()` already? That should give you the contents of the element (or attribute).

Comment: @henry - the object reference, the standard output from `Object.toString()`? It should give more information [according to the javadoc..](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html#toString\(\))

Comment: XmlObject.xmlText() gives me the whole chunk of Xml instead. What I want is the text that is between each tag. So I did xmlobject.getDomNode.toString(), it gave me the object reference. And getDomNode.getTextContent() gives me an exception.

Answer (score 0):

From an XmlObject you can get to the underlying xml document in many ways.  See `.newReader()`, `.newDomNode()`, `.newCusrsor()`, or `.xmlText()`.